# Do SCP and SFTP come installed on ubuntu by default?

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, scp

I'm using a Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS installed on a VM. I don't remember I installed SCP or SFTP yet when I try to login to it using (WinSCP on win10 machine) I'm able to connect to it. I suspect maybe they do come along with SSH server, because and I did configured it once. In the contrary, I had to install `vsftpd` manually to connect to this machine using `sudo apt install vsftpd` to be able to use `ftp`. My question is: are both `sftp` and `scp` installed by default on ubuntu? Or they got installed/configured when configuring SSH server? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

`scp` and `sftp` protocols are provided by `ssh` package.

It is not installed by default.

Comment: Thanks! it makes sense now!